# Matlab - Run simulink simulation in loop

Tags: matlab, simulink

Im using a Simulink model in a loop, by changing a parameter.

```
for i = 1:length(c_slip_sweep);
   ...
   c_slip=c_slip_sweep(i)
   tic; [tt2{i},xx2{i},yy2{i}]=sim(model,stop_time); toc
   ...
end
```

As the model spend much time to perform (100s), I'm trying to optimize it.

I've only find the "Rapid Accelerator" simulation mode reducing to 70s. But I don't know if there is a better way. Can I compile the model once, and re-use it in the loop ?  Or can I give a vector instead a parameter (whithout Parallel Computing Toolbox) ?

Comment: Have you run the Simulink Profiler to identify if there are any bottlenecks in the model?  Are your variables tt2, xx2 and yy2 preallocated? (If not the slowness could be due to savng the results not in running the model.) If you have Simulink Coder then you may be able to use the RSIM target to speed up the simulation, but other than that there may not be much that you can do.

Comment: Thank you Phil. I've already used the profiler and preallocated my variables. I will look for the RSIM target.